# Bootstrap "collapse-toggle" div will expand but wont contract back in

Tags: css

My Bootstrap div will expend but wont contract back in when viewed on the browser. However, works fine in the Dreamweaver view.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-template-toolbar">
<ul>
    <li><a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo"><b>Register</b><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>My Account</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Help centre</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Branch Finder</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Accessability</b></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
<!--Content Goes Here-->
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the data-target attribute on your toggle element.

Try:

```
<div id="top-template-toolbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" href="#demo"><b>Register</b><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>My Account</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>Help centre</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>Branch Finder</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>Accessability</b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        Content
    </div>
```

@ionut spataru: He is not adding bootstrap twice. once its the js and once the css so thats fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here with the same problem: 
- he is adding bootstrap twice in the page as you can see.

Add Jquery, after this add bootstrap, both of them only once, also it's a good habit to add all css files before the js files because some scripts make use of the css classes.